# User system in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm building an app that will run on our network for job tracking with two user levels, one for general users and one for administrators.

How are user systems usually implemented in Qt?  For example, how are user state and user roles handled?  Should I just include a C++ class and set these types of things as properties within that class, or are there established and well documented "best practices" for implementing user systems within Qt?

I also need to be able to share user state and role among various classes.  For example, the menu class needs to know the user state & role to know what items to display.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to access the operating system users & authentication ? Or do you want to make your own ?

Comment: I want to make my own.  I've made user systems for plenty of web apps but I'm generally unfamiliar with Qt.

Comment: The same ideas used in web apps should apply. I don't think that Qt gives you any specific things for that.

Comment: So state and role should be managed via sessions?

Comment: You can call that sessions if you like... IMHO web sessions are intimately related to HTTP cookies... But don't forget that a Qt application has only one user (& one display) at a single time (in contrast to a web server, dealing with many connections).

Comment: Forgive my complete ignorance.  If I set a value to a public property of a class (ie users->state), does that value persists as long as the application has not been closed, unless it is changed via a setter method?

Comment: Yes. Unless you modify it. And you might want to persist that data, e.g. to write it on disk somehow.

Comment: Cool, it looks like Qt supports that: http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/qsessionmanager.html  I appreciate all of your help - Thank you!  Please put some of this in an answer if you like so I can accept it = )

Comment: QSessionManager is for storing and restoring application state when the user re-logins (and the application is thus quit and restarted). It has nothing to do with user authentication and rights management.

Comment: @Frank Osterfield Yes, I was responding to Basile's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for doesn't make sense in terms of Qt on it's own.  Qt is a framework for local client apps.  The Qt application displays it's information to only 1 user at a time on one display / desktop at a time.

You framed the question in terms of a networked job tracking application.  Lets assume this implies there is some sort of job tracking server.  Likewise, let's assume you are writing a client for this server application in Qt.  In this model you could let the Qt application login to the server using credentials provided by the user.  Then it would be the server's job to tell you whether the user is who they claim to be and what role they have and to enforce any security restrictions.

Since you say you are familiar with web applications, lets draw an analogy.  Qt is intended to provide you the tools to write the web browser only;  you would still need to provide the the web server and web application to run within it.  Thus

```
Qt application is to web browser as X is to web server.
```

You have to provide "X", and that is where you implement the user system.

Of course Qt does provide basic support stuff like network sockets, but on it's own I don't think it's well suited to writing a server application.